# Query referring to dynamic array

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to combine the ranges A1:D13 from Sheet1 and Sheet2 into SheetA.
I have used a query function to do that, which works fine.

*query({Sheet1!$A$1:$D$13;Sheet2!$A$1:$D$13};"select * where...* etc.

However, sheets will keep increasing and I want to avoid going back and adding 'Sheet
Name'!XX:XX every time ending up with a long array with all {Sheet1!XX:XX;Sheet2!XX:XX...}.

I have tried the following two workarounds but keep failing:

1. *=query(Sheet!B1;"select ....* where SheetA!B1 contains a JOIN function to generate   *{Sheet1!XX:XX;Sheet1!XX:XX...}*
2. copying the JOIN function straight into the query as *query(JOIN(...

Can I somehow include a dynamic array in the query function?

Comment: Did you try `query({Sheet1$A$1:$D;Sheet2!$A$1:$D$};"` with `is not null` before? You don't have to specific the last row in query method

Comment: @Κιn Siang yes this is what I have.. I only used last row here to make it more clear. I only want to replace `{Sheet1$A$1:$D;Sheet2!$A$1:$D$}` with an equation that auto generates it or a cell reference that contains this

Comment: If new sheet keep create for storing data, you need to try on app script for automation. Otherwise you have to manually add the new sheet name into your formula, I think it won't take too many time to do it also.

Comment: Is there a finite number of possible sheets? I mean can you anticipate a maximum number of sheets to be added?